# PThreads is not providing a program speedup over serial code

Tags: c, linux, pthreads, matrix-multiplication

I am creating 2 programs to test the differences in run time of serial matrix multiply vs that of parallel matrix multiply. The parallel code that I have written is actually running slower than serial code, and running the program with additional cores enabled provides no speedup at all... *using more cores actually seems to slow down the parallel program.*

What is going on here? This is my parallel code: *to use this pass in matrix size and thread number (see my useage below)*

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>  // rand(), srand()
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <pthread.h>

// Time struct + prototypes
struct timespec time1, time2, diffTime;
struct timespec timespecDifference(struct timespec start, struct timespec end); // For timing
double** reserveMatrix(int nRows, int nCols);
void printMat(double** mat1, int rows, int cols);
void* matMult(void* arg);

// Argstruct
typedef struct {
    double** result;
    int tid;
    int size;
    int s;
    int e;
} argStr;

// global variables for use by all threads
int size;           // Size of a row and column. 
int numThreads;     // Number of pThreads to do work

double** mat1;
double** mat2;
double** mat3;

// Main function
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    size = atoi(argv[1]);
    numThreads = atoi(argv[2]);

    mat1 = reserveMatrix(size, size);
    mat2 = reserveMatrix(size, size);
    mat3 = reserveMatrix(size, size);

    if (size == 0) {
        //printf("Matrix cannot be size 0\n");
        return -1;
    }

    //Start timer
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &time1);

    // *********** Begin main operation *********** //
    //                                              //

    // declare necessary local variables
    pthread_t theThreads[numThreads];
    argStr data[numThreads];            // Create numThreads # of argStr objects
    for (int i = 0; i < numThreads; i++) {
        data[i].result = reserveMatrix(size, size);
        data[i].tid = i;       // Self-assigned threadID
        data[i].size = size;    // Size of a block
        data[i].s = size * i / numThreads;
        data[i].e = size * (i + 1) / numThreads - 1;
        //printf("I handle operations from %d to %d\n", data[i].s, data[i].e);
    }
    
    // Start the threads
    for (int i = 0; i < numThreads; i++) {
        pthread_create(&theThreads[i], NULL, matMult, (void*) (&data[i]));
    }

    // await all threads being done.
    for (int i = 0; i < numThreads; i++) {
        pthread_join(theThreads[i], NULL);
    }

    // rejoin received data
    //printMat(data[1].result, size, size);

    //                                              //
    // *********** End main operation ***********   //

    // Stop timer and find time taken
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &time2);
    diffTime = timespecDifference(time1, time2);
    double cpuTimeUsed = ((double)diffTime.tv_sec + (double)diffTime.tv_nsec / 1000000000.0);
    //Print Time
    printf("Pthread Matrix Multiply, %d, %d, %lf\n", size, numThreads, cpuTimeUsed);

}


// Struct Timer
struct timespec timespecDifference(struct timespec start, struct timespec end)
{
    struct timespec temp;
    if ((end.tv_nsec - start.tv_nsec) < 0) {
        temp.tv_sec = end.tv_sec - start.tv_sec - 1;
        temp.tv_nsec = 1000000000 + end.tv_nsec - start.tv_nsec;
    }
    else {
        temp.tv_sec = end.tv_sec - start.tv_sec;
        temp.tv_nsec = end.tv_nsec - start.tv_nsec;
    }
    return temp;
}

// Reserve matrix function
double** reserveMatrix(int nRows, int nCols) { 
    double** matrix1 = (double**)malloc(nRows * sizeof(double*));
    matrix1[0] = (double*)malloc(nRows * nCols * sizeof(double));
    
    // Assign row pointers to "segment" out the data
    for (int r = 1; r < nRows; ++r) {
        matrix1[r] = &(matrix1[0][r * nCols]);
    }

    // Give values to the array
    for(int i = 0; i < nRows * nCols; i++) {
        matrix1[0][i] = i; 
    }

    return matrix1;
}

// Print matrix function
void printMat(double** mat1, int rows, int cols) {
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
            printf("%f, ", mat1[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("End of array print\n");
}

void* matMult(void* arg) {

    //printf("Begin an operation\n");

    argStr* args = (argStr*)arg;
    double** result = args->result;
    int tid = args->tid;
    int size = args->size;  // Size of the matrix
    long s = args->s;    // Start
    long e = args->e;    // End

    // Print message to confirm data is getting stored
    //printf("Hello from operation %d! \n", tid);
    //printf("I am working from number %ld to %ld\n", s, e);

    for(int r = s; r <= e; r++) {        // May need to declare out of loop
        for(int c = 0; c < size; c++) {
            result[r][c] = 0.0;
            for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                result[r][c] += mat1[r][i] * mat2[i][c];
            }
        }
    }

    // Print multipled matrix values
    //printMat(mat3, size, size);
    return NULL;
}
```

This is my serial code: *To use this pass in the same sized row and column (see my useage below)*

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>  // rand(), srand()
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>
// Matrix multiply code

// **** Time struct **** //
struct timespec time1, time2, diffTime;

// Prototypes
struct timespec timespecDifference(struct timespec start, struct timespec end); // For timing
double** matrixMultiply(double** matrix1, double** matrix2, double** result, int nRows, int nCols);
double** transMatrixMultiply(double** matrix1, double** matrix2, double** result, int nRows, int nCols);
double** reserveMatrix(int nRows, int nCols);
double matrixProduct(double** mat1, double** mat2, int nRows, int nCols);
void printMat(double** mat1, int rows, int cols);

// Begin main
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int rows = atoi(argv[1]);
    int cols = atoi(argv[2]);

    // Declare the ARRAYS and populate them
    double** arr1 = reserveMatrix(rows, cols);
    double** arr2 = reserveMatrix(rows, cols);
    double** arr3 = reserveMatrix(rows, cols);
    double** arr4 = reserveMatrix(rows, cols);

    double prod1 = matrixProduct(arr1, arr2, rows, cols);
    
    //Start Clock
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &time1);
        
        arr3 = matrixMultiply(arr1, arr2, arr3, rows, cols);
    
    // Stop timer and find time taken
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &time2);
    diffTime = timespecDifference(time1, time2);
    double cpuTimeUsed = ((double)diffTime.tv_sec + (double)diffTime.tv_nsec / 1000000000.0);
    //Print Time
    printf("Matrix Multiply, %d, %lf\n", rows, cpuTimeUsed);
  

    // Print input matrix values. Used to test that matrix multiply works - it does
   


    // Perform a transposition of matrix 2

    for (int r = 0; r < rows; ++r) {
        for (int c = r + 1; c < cols; ++c) {
            double val = arr2[r][c];
            arr2[r][c] = arr2[c][r];
            arr2[c][r] = val;
        }
    }


    // Run matrix multiply again on the newly transposed data.
    //Start Clock
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &time1);

        arr4 = transMatrixMultiply(arr1, arr2, arr4, rows, cols);
   
   // Stop timer and find time taken
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &time2);
    diffTime = timespecDifference(time1, time2);
    cpuTimeUsed = ((double)diffTime.tv_sec + (double)diffTime.tv_nsec / 1000000000.0);
    //Print Time
    printf("Trans Matrix Multiply, %d, %lf\n", rows, cpuTimeUsed);
  


    //double prod2 = matrixProduct(arr3, arr4, rows, cols);
    //printf("The matrix product of m3 and m4 is: %f\n", prod2);

    //printMat(mat3, rows, cols);
    return 0;
} 

// Struct Timer
struct timespec timespecDifference(struct timespec start, struct timespec end)
{
    struct timespec temp;
    if ((end.tv_nsec - start.tv_nsec) < 0) {
        temp.tv_sec = end.tv_sec - start.tv_sec - 1;
        temp.tv_nsec = 1000000000 + end.tv_nsec - start.tv_nsec;
    }
    else {
        temp.tv_sec = end.tv_sec - start.tv_sec;
        temp.tv_nsec = end.tv_nsec - start.tv_nsec;
    }
    return temp;
}

// standard matrix multiply
double** matrixMultiply(double** matrix1, double** matrix2, double** result, int nRows, int nCols) {
    for (int r = 0; r < nRows; ++r) {
        for (int c = 0; c < nCols; ++c) {
            result[r][c] = 0.0;
            for (int i = 0; i < nRows; ++i) {
                result[r][c] += matrix1[r][i] * matrix2[i][c]; 
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}

// Transpose matrix multiply
double** transMatrixMultiply(double** matrix1, double** matrix2, double** result, int nRows, int nCols) {
    for (int c = 0; c < nCols; ++c) {
        for (int r = 0; r < nRows; ++r) {
            result[c][r] = 0.0;
            for (int i = 0; i < nCols; ++i) {
                result[c][r] += matrix1[c][i] * matrix2[r][i]; 
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}

// Reserve data function. Reserves and populates array data
double** reserveMatrix(int nRows, int nCols) {
    double** matrix1 = (double**)malloc(nRows * sizeof(double*));
    matrix1[0] = (double*)malloc(nRows * nCols * sizeof(double));
    
    // Assign row pointers to "segment" out the data
    for (int r = 1; r < nRows; ++r) {
        matrix1[r] = &(matrix1[0][r * nCols]);
    }

    // Give values to the array
    for(int i = 0; i < nRows * nCols; i++) {
        matrix1[0][i] = i; 
    }

    return matrix1;
}

// Check that matrix1 and matrix2 are the same
double matrixProduct(double** mat1, double** mat2, int nRows, int nCols) {
    double sum = 0.0;
    for(int i = 0; i < nRows * nCols; i++) {
        sum += (mat1[0][i] - mat2[0][i]) * (mat1[0][i] - mat2[0][i]);
        //printf("matrix product pos: %i, sum: %f\n", i, sum);
    }
    return sum;
}

// Print matrix function
void printMat(double** mat1, int rows, int cols) {
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
            printf("%f, ", mat1[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("End of array print\n");
}
```

Here is the linux output of me compiling and running this code. At matrix size 1200 x 1200 the run time differences are not that pronounced, but the serial code ends up being significantly faster than the parallel at sizes above 1500 x 1500:

- MYPC:~/Projects/matrixMultiply/phase3$ gcc matrixMult.c -o MM
- MYPC:~/Projects/matrixMultiply/phase3$ gcc pMatMult.c -lpthread -o PMM
- MYPC:~/Projects/matrixMultiply/phase3$ ./MM 1200 1200
- **Matrix Multiply, 1200, 25.487388**
- **Trans Matrix Multiply, 1200, 16.452777**
- MYPC:~/Projects/matrixMultiply/phase3$ ./PMM 1200 2
- **Pthread Matrix Multiply, 1200, 2, 22.495115**
- MYPC:~/Projects/matrixMultiply/phase3$ ./PMM 1200 4
- **Pthread Matrix Multiply, 1200, 4, 22.181686**

The sections in bold contain the meaningful output. It reads

- name of the process
- matrix size
- number of threads spawned (in pThread program only)
- run time

Any help would be appreciated. I will be instantly replying to questions for the next 2 hours.

Comment: Using multiple threads does NOT guarantee a speed up.  There's extra overhead in coordinating between threads (the less need to coordinate, the easier it is to get a speed up), and if there's a bottleneck such as the I/O subsystem, then adding threads won't speed things up (and may slow things down).

Comment: I copy-pasted your code and get a pretty linear speedup up to 16 cores. Are you sure your hardware actually has multiple cores, and that threads get scheduled on them? Have you considered enabling `-O2`?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler do you know if multiple threads reading from a global variable is a bottleneck? I know that threads writing to a global variable can be.... In my case, I have the threads reading from global matrices 1 and 2 to do their calculations.

Comment: @EugeneSh. the matrix size is 1200 x 1200. The thread count is 2 and 4 on my test cases

Comment: @thatotherguy I have compiled and ran this code using O2 and I did not observe a speedup... (I have been working with this for a few days now haha). I am certain that my hardware has 4 cores, but is there a way I can test that threads are getting scheduled on them? EDIT: I have tested to ensure that multiple threads are being spawned - I am certain that is happening. Whether or not they're distributed across the cores, I don't know how to test

Comment: If you're protecting the global variable from multiple threads accessing it simultaneously, then yes, there is a bottleneck.  If you're not protecting it from being modified, then you have a race condition and unpredictable behaviour.  Global variables and threads are not a good mixture.  If you can partition the workload so that there is no contention over the global variable (e.g. if it is a big array and thread 1 works on a disjoint section from thread 2, thread 3, …, thread N) then you don't have a bottleneck.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler roger that. I don't believe that I am protecting my global variables. I am aware that constantly toggling something like a mutex on a global variable can be very taxing to run time... Do you see something in my code that may be implicitly locking and unlocking global variables? EDIT: Does simply reading, but not writing to a global variable lock it?

Comment: C doesn't do 'implicit locking' — you have to do explicit locking.  I've not read your code thoroughly; I'm spouting generalities.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Gotcha - much appreciated. I will continue to try and understand that better. To try and get around that problem, I re-allocated my results matrix (numThreads) times and passed deep copies off to the threads in order to avoid race conditions or locking... maybe that didn't work?

Comment: @thatotherguy What options did you use when compiling the parallel code? I'd like to try the same set of options and see if that provides the expected speedup.

Comment: The only potential problem I can see is 2 or more CPUs writing to (different parts of) the same cache line, causing a cache line to rapidly bounce between CPUs. Would suggest using a temporary variable in the inner loop (replace `result[r][c] += matrix1[r][i] * matrix2[i][c]; ` with `temp += matrix1[r][i] * matrix2[i][c];` and store the temporary variable once outside the loop).

Comment: I ran `gcc foo.c -lpthread -o foo && gcc bar.c -o bar && ./foo 1200 1 && ./foo 1200 2 && ./foo 1200 4 && ./bar 1200 1200` and it gave `24.585925`, `11.848569`, `6.041378`, `23.588583`

Comment: @thatotherguy incredible... I compiled using the same method and got my above, not sped up results. The numbers you got are expected, which means the code should be working. Any ideas what may be wrong on my end that would be causing pthreads to seemingly not distribute work across my 4 cores?

Comment: @Brendan That seems like a good idea. To be clear, you're suggesting creating a local, temporary matrix to store results to, and then write the results all at once outside of the loop?

Comment: @oXeru Does `top -1` show that all four cores are in use, and that your executable is using 400% CPU with no significant other usage?

Comment: @thatotherguy here is a printout of top -n 10 https://pastebin.com/EMY4qxTy. My naïve interpretation of those results is that I have a lot of other processes running on my machine, causing any speedups to be kneecapped.

Comment: It's pretty weird that you have 8 processes eating CPU while still at "95.9 id". I'd definitely try this on different hardware, preferably a non-virtual machine not shared with any other users

Comment: @thatotherguy Ill see if I can do that - Thank you for the help! If anything else pops into your mind at some point, I anticipate that I will still be working on this problem for a little while longer.

Comment: In `reserveMatrix`, you have UB. Because you don't have a true 2D array but a 1D array of pointers to 1D `double` arrays, the third loop goes beyond the end of the array after `i >= nCols`: `for (int i = 0; i < nRows * nCols; i++) matrix1[0][i] = i;` You need: `int i = 0; for (int irow = 0; i < nRows; ++irow) for (int icol = 0; i < nCols; ++icol) matrix1[irow][icol] = i++;`

Comment: Also, I'm not sure you can do a transpose "in-place". Certainly not if `nRows != nCols`

Comment: @oXeru: I'm suggesting that (e.g.) if a cache line is 64 bytes and contains the last few entries of one row of the result matrix, 16 bytes of "malloc header" wastage, then the first few entries of a different row; 2 CPUs could be doing `result[r][c] += matrix1[r][i] * matrix2[i][c]; ` at the same time causing the cache line to bounce from one CPU to another for every iteration of that inner loop; and (with a plain `double temp;` local variable) doing `temp += matrix1[r][i] * matrix2[i][c];` inside the loop and `result[r][c] = temp;` outside avoids most cache line bouncing.

Comment: @oXeru: I'd also say that using "array of pointers to each row" (instead of "2D array") isn't great for performance; because each time a CPU moves to the next row you get unpredictable/unprefetchable data accesses; and (because of the cost of extra pointers plus the cost of "malloc headers" and padding/alignment) in extreme cases (e.g. small number of columns with huge number of rows) your cache (and TLB) efficiency could be severely impacted (e.g. cache containing 75% pollution and 25% data you actually use). Of course that would apply to both single-threaded and multi-threaded equally.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to terminate extra processes that were running on my ubuntu machine. The code worked perfectly fine as a few users pointed out. Killing all other processes on the machine, then running my parallel code provided the expected speedups.

I am not sure of the precise technical reason this is going on other than the machine wasn't prioritizing my program when it had others running, resulting in slower times.